# Knockout.js: knockout-sortable css update from oberservableArray

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the great knockout.js lib together with jQuery and jQuery-UI in some web project.

In a special view of my application I list a set of tasks. These tasks should be sortable so I thought about the sortable-widget of jQuery-UI. As I'm also using Knockout I found this very helpful lib of Ryan Niemeyer called knockout-sortable which combines the jQuery-sortable with the Knockout function.

Listing the tasks in a `<ul>`-element is no problem, also moving the corresponding `<li>`-elements around work perfect.

```
<div class="container" data-bind="sortable: tasks">
        <div class="item"  data-bind="css: {highlight:marked}">
            <span>
                <p>
                    <span data-bind="text: id"></span>: 
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                </p>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

But I need a special function: each time some task is moved up or down the list there should be all IDs of the predecessors-task in the list saved to a separate array (predecessors-array). To make it more clear: I need the information until which task/`<li>`-entry the list is modified because I want to do something later with the tasks from position `[0..<highestIndexOfMovedTask>]`. For that I save all preceding task-IDs in a separate array.

So I do this in the "afterMove" function of Niemeyer's knockout-sortable. This works fine and all IDs are saved to the predecessors-array.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = function(obj){
    var targetIdx = obj.targetIndex+1;
    if(targetIdx>viewModel.highestTargetId()){
       viewModel.highestTargetId(targetIdx);
    }
    var allItemsUntilTarget = viewModel.tasks().slice(0, viewModel.highestTargetId());
    var itemIdsUntilTarget = $.map(allItemsUntilTarget, function(elem, idx){return elem.id()});
    var oldProducts = viewModel.includeIds.removeAll();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(viewModel.includeIds, itemIdsUntilTarget);  
};
```

The next step makes it complicated: Of course there should be a visual representation of all task which IDs are in the predecessors-array. For that there is a computed-observable property called "marked" on each task checking if the own ID is in the predecessors-array. Every time some task is moved in the list the marked-property is newly computed to true/false if the task is in the predecessors-array or not.

This also works fine but if I bind a CSS class to the marked-property to indicate visually that this task is in the predecessors-array there is no update of the CSS. I tried yesterday 5h and did a lot of research but I didn't come up with a solution. While the model is correctly updated (which can be checked via the developer console of chrome) the view is not.

Maybe someone can help me out with that?! I posted some test code here: http://jsfiddle.net/njLrxhd5/3

Any help is really welcome! Thank you..

---

Edit: Thanks for the first answers. Initial look:

[image]

My expected result after moving the initial `53:Fix car` to position 4 behind `456:fix fence` should be:

[image: Expected result]

So all tasks should have set their marked-property to `true` if they have a lower position in the task-array than the position of the task which was moved to the highest position in the array.

The view-model of the MVVM is already correctly responding, but the View isn't updating.

Comment: Still not clear exactly what this "predecessors-array" is supposed to represent, but I do see that you're adding new observables *after* calling ko.applyBindings. I don't think you'll get the behavior you're looking for unless those observables exist at the time you call applyBindings.

Answer (score 0):

Before move

[image: before move]

*After moving 465: Walk dog UI is like this*
[image: after move]

Updated output as per your comments:

[image: possible output]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njLrxhd5/26/

In your after move

```
  /*Reset the array so that UI sortable is refreshed */ 
    var array= ko.toJS(viewModel.tasks);

    viewModel.tasks.removeAll();
    viewModel.tasks(array);
```

basically it repopulates the task array so that sortable UI is refreshed.

*Please note*: 
There might be some efficient way to do this kind of updates(like parent subscribing to child or there might be some option in knockout sortable). I was just testing the update feature

Comment: Hey Rohith, thanks for your answer. All entries with their ID in includeIds should be highlighted in red. That is because their marked-property is actually `true` but this is not triggered in the UI...

Comment: @dacrow I have updated the answer based on your comments